# sorting data frame and calculating instant value of a column

Tags: r, dataframe, date, sorting, group-by

I have a relatively large data frame (1.5 million rows and 5 columns). For simplicity, I created a sample data frame below:

```
date <- c("2018-07-06","2017-04-13","2017-09-12","2018-09-19"
          ,"2019-03-04","2017-05-21","2018-05-15")
data <- as.Date(date)
TV_ad<-c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
ID <- c(1315769,1300620,1300620,1315769,1300620,1315769,1300620)
result <- data.frame(ID,TV_ad,date)


       ID TV_ad       date
1 1315769     0 2018-07-06
2 1300620     1 2017-04-13
3 1300620     0 2017-09-12
4 1315769     0 2018-09-19
5 1300620     1 2019-03-04
6 1315769     0 2017-05-21
7 1300620     1 2018-05-15
```

what I want to do, for each specific ID, at the specific time, I want to calculate the ratio number of times that person used TV_ad on all previous dates. The simplest way I can imagine is to select a specific ID first, then sort the small dataframe based on the date and calculate ratio of TV_ad for each date. for example for **ID=1300620** first I build a small data frame which is sorted by **date**like this:

```
    ID    TV_ad       date
2 1300620     1 2017-04-13
3 1300620     0 2017-09-12
7 1300620     1 2018-05-15
5 1300620     1 2019-03-04
```

then I can calculate the ratio for each row. For the first row, it's 1/1=1 for the second row, 1/2=0.5 for the third one 2/3=0.66 and for the forth 3/4=0.75

I get this result:

```
       ID TV_ad       date ratio
1 1315769     0 2018-07-06  0.00
2 1300620     1 2017-04-13  1.00
3 1300620     0 2017-09-12  0.50
4 1315769     0 2018-09-19  0.00
5 1300620     1 2019-03-04  0.75
6 1315769     0 2017-05-21  0.00
7 1300620     1 2018-05-15  0.66
```

However, this method would be time-consuming on my large dataset. Any suggestion to do this calculation faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to split data, you can do it all on 1 data.frame using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)   

result %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ratio = cumsum(TV_ad) / seq_len(n()))
```

gives:

```
       ID TV_ad date       ratio
    <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
1 1300620     1 2017-04-13 1    
2 1300620     0 2017-09-12 0.5  
3 1300620     1 2018-05-15 0.667
4 1300620     1 2019-03-04 0.75 
5 1315769     0 2017-05-21 0    
6 1315769     0 2018-07-06 0    
7 1315769     0 2018-09-19 0
```

or you can use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(result)
result <- result[order(ID, date)]
result[, ratio := cumsum(TV_ad) / seq_len(.N), by = ID]
```

(you don't need to order by `ID` it's purely for output text visibility)

Comment: Is there any way to change this, so we calculate the ratio up to the row we are interested in? so basically so for example, today is 2018-05-15 and I want to calculate the ratio at this point but only consider TV_ad until that time

Comment: I am thinking about
mutate(ratio1 = (cumsum(TV_ad)) / seq_len(n()-1), ratio2=TV_ad/seq_len(n()-1))
but this will result in NAN for the first row of each dataframe as 1-1 is equal to 0

Comment: Depends what you want your output to look like, if you want to drop rest of the rows you can add filter into pipe prior to calculation  `filter(date <= as.Date("2018-05-15"))`, or if you want to keep all rows you can use `ifelse(date <= as.Date("2018-05-15"), cumsum(TV_ad) / seq_len(n()), NA)`

Comment: and also at start, you need to convert your `date` from factor to date class with: `mutate(date = as.Date(as.character(date)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
> result_ord <- result[order(result$ID, result$date), ]
> result_ord$cumAvg_by_ID <- ave(result_ord$TV_ad, list(result_ord$ID), FUN=function(x) cumsum(x) / 1:length(x) )
```

OUTPUT:

```
> result_ord
       ID TV_ad       date cumAvg_by_ID
2 1300620     1 2017-04-13    1.0000000
3 1300620     0 2017-09-12    0.5000000
7 1300620     1 2018-05-15    0.6666667
5 1300620     1 2019-03-04    0.7500000
6 1315769     0 2017-05-21    0.0000000
1 1315769     0 2018-07-06    0.0000000
4 1315769     0 2018-09-19    0.0000000
>
```

(As noted by @det above, only ordering by `date` is absolutely necessary).

Reference:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-October/255987.html